# Football score swapping: is it ok?

Tags: football

I'm developing a football application. A two-legged tie looks like this:

```
TeamA  1:0  TeamB
TeamB  4:2  TeamA
<sum of goals 3:4, sum of wins 1:1, winner TeamB>
```

Is it easy to understand? The sum is actually calculated diagonally, and the order of sums corresponds to the first leg (match).

May I rearrange all this so that it would be understandable and correct? May I fold the first two lines like following?

```
TeamA 1:0, 2:4 TeamB
```

Or it is untraditional and weird to swap the score this way?

There may be objections that this question should be moved to User Experience site, but the question is more about how is right, rather than how is more convenient.

Comment: Before reading the last note I was about to suggest you to post on UX.SE.

Comment: Someone must have had that problem before. Did you check [what they came up with](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014%E2%80%9315_UEFA_Champions_League#First_qualifying_round)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's important isn't the format per se; it could pretty much be formatted anyway you see fit (that is, with regards to design and user-friendliness). The way I see it, you can do it anyway you want - just as long as it's clear which team was the home team in each game.

You probably already know this, but for a reader who's new to football; the two-legged tie is often determined on the number of away goals, when each team has won one game each and the goal difference is the same. This makes it very important that it is clear which team was the home (and away-) team in each game.

Apart from that, you should simply find a good looking way of presenting the scores :)